# Xhrpost not hitting the controller(url)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dojo

I am trying to post data to mvc controller and i am unsuccessful doing so..hope i get any help...here is the xhrpost call

```
var reqObj =
                {
                    Id: dojo.byId("Id").value,
                    Password: dojo.byId("Password").value
                };
                console.log(reqObj );
                var xhrArgs = {
                    url: '~/FormController/ValidateRequest',
                    postData: reqObj ,
                    handleAs: "json",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"},
                    load: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
            var deffered = dXhr.post(xhrArgs);
            console.log(deffered);
           }
```

I could not even see a post call in firebug....what might be the problem..any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple issues:
First you populate `reqObj` with the values you want to post, however, you put "`request`" into your xhrArgs.

Second, you will need to convert `reqObj` to json (`dojo.toJson`), since you are handling the post as json.

Also, I don't see a reference to the dojo.xhrPost method?  Are you using sometype of framework that encapsulates that?

Comment: First one is a typo..my bad.. i converted the object to json and posted it...i can see the post call in firebug but it is unable to hit the controller action..am i specifying this  url: '~/FormController/ValidateRequest' correct?

Comment: What is firebug telling you the exception is?  I suspect it's that you are trying to call the controller\action directly rather than calling the route.  Try /Form/ValidateRequest.

Comment: What is firebug telling you the exception is?

Comment: hmm figured it out url should be like this url:'ValidateRequest/'